# 403 forbidden while accessing /oauth/token in spring oauth

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, oauth, spring-security

I am trying to implement Spring oauth 2.0 and I am getting 403 Forbidden error.

Spring-security.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:oauth="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"    
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2.xsd       
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

    <!-- Stateless RESTful services use BASIC authentication -->
    <security:http use-expressions="true" auto-config='true' create-session="stateless" authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/oauth/**" access="isAnonymous()"/>
                <security:intercept-url pattern="/rest/**" />
        <security:http-basic/>

        <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"/>  
    </security:http>
    <oauth:authorization-server client-details-service-ref="client-details-service" token-services-ref="tokenServices">  
        <oauth:authorization-code />  
        <oauth:implicit />  
        <oauth:refresh-token />  
        <oauth:client-credentials />  
  <oauth:password authentication-manager-ref="authenticationOauthManager"/>   
    </oauth:authorization-server> 
    <beans:bean id="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"  
      class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter">  
    <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>  
    </beans:bean> 

    <beans:bean id="jdbcDaoImpl" class="org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.jdbc.JdbcDaoImpl">
        <beans:property name="enableGroups" value="true" />
         <beans:property name="enableAuthorities" value="false" />
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </beans:bean> 

    <!-- Oauth Client Verification Configuration -->
    <oauth:client-details-service id="client-details-service">


        <!-- Web Application clients -->
        <oauth:client
                client-id="NofaAdmin"
                secret="655f523128212d6e70634446224c2a48"
                authorized-grant-types="password,refresh_token,authorization_code"

                access-token-validity="5184000"
                refresh-token-validity="5184000"
                />
</oauth:client-details-service>



    <beans:bean id="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint"
          class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <beans:property name="typeName" value="Basic"/>
    </beans:bean>



    <beans:bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"
          class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler"/>  
    <!-- Token Generation -->
    <beans:bean id="tokenServices" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices">  
        <beans:property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore"/>  
        <beans:property name="supportRefreshToken" value="true"/>  
        <beans:property name="clientDetailsService" ref="client-details-service"/>  
    </beans:bean>

    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationOauthManager">
        <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:user-service>
        <security:user name="admin" password="password" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        </security:user-service>
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>
<!--    Storing Generated Tokens In Database
 -->     <!-- <beans:bean id="tokenStore" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JdbcTokenStore">
       <beans:constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
    </beans:bean>  -->
        <beans:bean id="tokenStore" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.InMemoryTokenStore"/>  

    <oauth:resource-server id="resourceServerFilter" token-services-ref="tokenServices"/>

    <!-- Security JDBC Authentication Manager -->
    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <security:authentication-provider>
           <security:jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
          users-by-username-query=
          "select email,password,1 from USER where email=?" 

            authorities-by-username-query=
            "select * from ROLE r INNER JOIN (select * from USER u INNER JOIN ROLE_USER ru on u.ID=ru.USER_ID where u.email=? limit 1) roleobj on roleobj.ROLE_ID=r.ID"/>
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
<!-- <security:global-method-security jsr250-annotations="enabled" access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager"/>  
    <beans:bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased">  
    <beans:property name="decisionVoters">   
        <beans:list>  
            <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.access.annotation.Jsr250Voter"/>  
        </beans:list>  
    </beans:property>  
</beans:bean>  -->
```

Application Context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"   
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
<beans default-autowire="byName">
    <!-- 
        <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="m2m"/>
        </bean>
    -->


    <bean id="currencyRateService"
        class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="m2m/CurrencyRateService/remote" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="reportService"
        class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="m2m/ReportService/remote" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="invoiceService"
        class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="m2m/InvoiceService/remote" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="entercarduserService"
        class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="m2m/EnterCardUserService/remote" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="userService"
        class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="m2m/UserService/remote" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="userLoginStatusService"
        class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="m2m/UserLoginStatusService/remote" />
    </bean>
    <!--  <bean id="campaignService"
        class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="m2m/CampaignService/remote" />
    </bean> -->
    <bean id="rewardService"
        class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="m2m/RewardService/remote" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="partnerService"
        class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="m2m/PartnerService/remote" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="socialService"
        class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="m2m/SocialService/remote" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="activityService"
        class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="m2m/ActivityService/remote" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="constantService"
        class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="m2m/ConstantService/remote" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="regionService"
        class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="m2m/RegionService/remote" />
    </bean>
    <!-- <bean id="verificationService"
        class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName"
            value="m2m/VerificationService/remote" />
    </bean> -->

    <bean id="trophyService"
        class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="m2m/TrophyService/remote" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="contentService"
        class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="m2m/ContentService/remote" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="templateService"
        class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="m2m/TemplateService/remote" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="partnerUISettingService"
        class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName"  value="m2m/PartnerUISettingService/remote" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="java:/M2MDS" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Cache -->
    <!-- <bean id="cacheManager" class="net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager" factory-method="getInstance" />  -->
    <bean id="cacheManager"
        class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:ehcache.xml" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionCache"
        class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheFactoryBean">
        <property name="cacheManager" ref="cacheManager" />
        <property name="cacheName" value="m2msession" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="applicationCache"
        class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheFactoryBean">
        <property name="cacheManager" ref="cacheManager" />
        <property name="cacheName" value="m2mapplication" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="contextCache"
        class="com.sinarotech.m2m.web.cache.EhcacheContextCache">
        <property name="sessionCache" ref="sessionCache" />
        <property name="applicationCache" ref="applicationCache" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Utils -->
    <bean id="contactImporter"
        class="com.sinarotech.m2m.contact.OZContactImporter" />

    <bean id="helperUtils"
        class="com.sinarotech.m2m.web.util.HelperUtils">
        <property name="userService" ref="userService" />
        <property name="constantService" ref="constantService" />
        <property name="rewardService" ref="rewardService" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="pecuniosusManager"
        class="com.sinarotech.m2m.service.PecuniosusManager"
        factory-method="getInstance" />

    <bean id="config" class="com.sinarotech.m2m.util.Configuration"
        factory-method="getInstance" />

    <bean id="tipsFactory"
        class="com.sinarotech.m2m.web.util.TipsFactory">
        <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="tips.drl" />
        <property name="config" ref="config" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="affiliateHandlerFactory"
        class="com.sinarotech.m2m.affiliate.AffiliateHandlerFactory"
        factory-method="getInstance" />

    <bean id="twitterHandler"
        class="com.sinarotech.m2m.twitter.AtomTwitterHandler" />

    <bean id="bankManager"
        class="com.sinarotech.m2m.service.BankManager"
        factory-method="getInstance" />

    <bean id="exchangeManager"
        class="com.sinarotech.m2m.web.util.ExchangeManager">
        <constructor-arg value="exchange.properties" />
        <property name="userService" ref="userService" />
        <property name="contextCache" ref="contextCache" />
    </bean>
 <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping"/> 
    <bean id="supportProvider"
        class="com.sinarotech.m2m.support.HelpspotSupportProvider" />



<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
        <property name="messageConverters">
            <list>
                                <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter"/>
                <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter"/>
                <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.SourceHttpMessageConverter"/>
                <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter"/>
                <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter"/>
            </list>
        </property>

    </bean>
</beans>
</beans>
```

I am not getting any exception in my code.Can someone point out what is wring in the configuration part.I am trying to integrate Spring Security Oauth to a Struts application

Thank you

Comment: Can you turn on debug logging in Log4j or similar which you have and when you attempt to access token, you will see some information in log, post it as stacktrace in main post.

Comment: Impossible to answer with the info you've provided. Most likely you're not sending proper HTTP requests.